# Flutter App Introduction with User Interaction

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to create an Animated App Walkthrough however I don't want something like Onboarding Screen.Let me give you an example to make it clear what I wanted :

For Example assume user login the app for the first time then the user needs to follow some instructions in order to learn the basics and unknown things of the app. So rather than a simple image or animation at Onboarding Screen, I want user to interact(touch) the shown places on the app.

Also , I look at flare where I could create animation but I couldnt find how to add interaction which I exactly want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Material Design* solution to this problem is [Feature Discovery](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/growth-communications/feature-discovery.html#).

There is a [package for this on Pub called `feature_discovery`](https://pub.dev/packages/feature_discovery).

---

The following content was **removed**.

There are not any standalone implementations in the form of plugins for Flutter that I am aware of available at the moment. However, there is an open source implementation created by Matthew Carrol, which was [published on GitHub](https://github.com/matthew-carroll/flutter_ui_challenge_feature_discovery).
Alongside the code, he created an in-depth video tutorial showing and explaining the creation process: https://youtu.be/Xm0ELlBtNWM.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your answer. That will definitly be a solution in my case :)

Comment: This is the library base on matthew on github https://github.com/ayalma/feature_discovery